# Issue with SQL Syntax inner join, where, like

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, inner-join, sql-like

What is wrong with the syntax?  its been wrecking my head for ages.  Could someone scan their eyes over it please?

```
SELECT C_Name, C_StreetNumber, C_StreetName, C_Postcode, C_County, C_Tele, C_Website, Contact_Forename, Contact_Surname, Contact_Email, Job_Type, Job_Price
FROM Company, Jobs ON Company.Company_ID = Jobs.Company_ID 
WHERE Company.C_County LIKE %belfast% AND Jobs.Job_Type LIKE %virus%
```

Comment: Remove the comma and replace it with the word `JOIN`... `FROM Company JOIN Jobs`  You're also missing single quotes around your like clauses -- `like '%belfast%'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use explicit `JOIN` when you use `ON`. If not you need to join the two tables in the `WHERE` clause. 
Also you have to select columns that don't have the same column in both tables otherwise you need to select them as table.column. e.g.

```
SELECT Company.C_Name, Company.C_StreetNumber, C_StreetName, C_Postcode, C_County, C_Tele, C_Website, Contact_Forename, Contact_Surname, Contact_Email, Job_Type, Job_Price
FROM Company
INNER JOIN Jobs
ON Company.Company_ID = Jobs.Company_ID 
WHERE Company.C_County LIKE '%belfast%' AND Jobs.Job_Type LIKE '%virus%'
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause?rq=1).

Comment: Why do you think `C_Name` needs the table qualifier?

Comment: Just to show the case.